# Change notification content when received

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to change the notification content before it displays on the device? For example: i have a user named John that is subscribed to a topic named food, i send a push notification to that topic with this title "Good morning username", but the device would display "Good morning John"

I wish to know if that is posible on android or iOS and how

Comment: Did you try overriding `onMessageReceived` of `FirebaseMessagingService`?

Comment: no i haven't tried that, is it posible to change the notification itself with onMessageReceived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Android**, 
yes, it is possible by overriding `onMessageReceived` of `FirebaseMessagingService`

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // Check your notification is not null and subcribed to `food` topic.
    if(remoteMessage.getFrom() == "food" &&
        remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){ 
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(); // Title from the notification. E.g `Good morning`

        // Get the `username` of the user stored in the device. Use SharedPreference.

        String message = title + " " + username; // "Good morning username"
        // Call your notification here.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure for since I applied this on android only. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with iOS but I think it is possible. Here's a reference on receiving notification for iOS: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive

Hope it can help you.

Comment: On iOS you can use the mutable-content field that allows you to manipulate the notification before being displayed to the user. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/modifying_content_in_newly_delivered_notifications